# htaccess Redirect with Variable carried over

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a numerous amount of 404s. 
Some old sites linked to
`http://example.com/product.tmpl?SKU=XXX`
with `XXX` being the numerical SKU number.

I want it to redirect to
`http://example.com/product.php?SKU=XXX`

This is where I've gotten to but it still isn't working. Do I have a typo in my code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SKU=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?product\.tmpl$ /product.php?SKU=%1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT: My full htaccess file reads as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SKU=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?product\.tmpl$ /product.php?SKU=%1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: "isn't working" - what _exactly_ is happening? Anything? What you have looks OK. Although it could be tidied a bit.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't doing anything at all I still try the old URL and it's going to the same 404 page

Comment: Ok, I have to ask... is mod_rewrite enabled? Are you permitted to use mod_rewrite in .htaccess files (ie. is the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive set in your server config)? Is `Options +FollowSymLinks` set?

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled. `AllowOverride` and `Options +FollowSymLinks` should all be set as well as this is a wordpress based site.

Comment: "a wordpress based site." - The directives above need to go _above_ any other directives (ie. the WordPress stuff) in your .htaccess file.

Comment: I've got to have something wrong. Edited main question with full htaccess

Comment: Enable logging of redirects in apache config. See how the pattern evaluates.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? 301 redirects are cached by the browser, which could include any previous mistakes. Presumably if you directly request `http://example.com/product.php?SKU=XXX` it works as expected? What you have looks OK, providing the URLs you've quoted are correct. As mentioned, it could be tidied a bit, but this wouldn't really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?product\.tmpl$ /product.php [L,QSA]
```

Modifier QSA keeps the query string whatever it is: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: You don't need the `QSA` flag if you aren't actually specifying a query string in the substitution; the query string is automatically appended. You only _need_ the QSA flag when you want to combine query strings. However, this will redirect (or at least should redirect) if the `SKU` parameter is omitted entirely.

Comment: @w3d The match `^/?product\.tmpl$` is done on the filepath only, not the entire request, that would be `%{THE_REQUEST}`, thus, it will work with and w/o any query params.

Comment: Exactly, it "will redirect if the SKU parameter is omitted entirely."